# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ from C#, None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

just spined a test RabbitMQ broker in AWS, trying to connect to it but it's not working
always getting the exception `None of the specified endpoints were reachable`
code sample:

```
[Fact]
public void RabbitConnection() {
  var cf = new ConnectionFactory() {
    HostName = "longguid.amazonaws.com",
      Password = "pass",
      UserName = "user",
      Port = 5671
  };
  // Act
  var con = cf.CreateConnection();

  // Assert
  Assert.True(true);
}
```

no matter how I flip the endpoint it's not working
adding the `amqps://` prefix or removing it, adding the port att the end of the hostname or through the property, use the uri property instead of hostname,set the ssl property to no matter what(tls.none, tls.1 ... etc) , it's not working at all!
tried on two systems (ubuntu, win10) 3 different networks

though I can reach the endpoint from commandline using nc and telnet
output from terminal

```
mohamed@xxxxxxx3:~$ nc -zv xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxx.amazonaws.com 5671
Connection to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxx.amazonaws.com 5671 port [tcp/amqps] succeeded!
mohamed@xxxxxxx3:~$ telnet xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxx.amazonaws.com 5671
Trying 16.111.11.11...
Connected to rabbit-broker-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.xx-xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
mohamed@xxxxxxx3:~$
```

note: the connection while using telnet coleses after ~5 seconds.

also I can login to rabbit dashboard (different url of course) using the same credentials

Comment: can you try running a local rabbitmq engine and try connecting to that. (You can use a docker image for easy setup)

Comment: hmm,
running rabbit container in docker using the following command
`docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3`
and set the connection factory to `var cf=new ConnectionFactory()
{HostName="localhost"};`
got it to work
very confusing!

Comment: Then you should check the firewall in AWS. Allow inbound connection from the client IP.

Comment: thanks for helping, I tried on ubuntu os where the firewall is inactive same thing,
finally found the fix with help from a colleague
`var cf=new ConnectionFactory()
{HostName="longguid.amazonaws.com",Password="pass",UserName="user",Ssl=new SslOption("longguid.amazonaws.com",enabled:true)};`

Comment: you should post this as an answer